# Spring Boot 2 with Spock Integration tests - app context is not starting on test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spock

I have a weird problem with my spock tests, the spring context is not starting when running in tests. I ran throw all the questions here, checked the needed dependencies and still getting NPE when calling the autowired dependencies.

My setup: Spring Boot 2.0.0, Spock 1.1, Groovy 2.4.14.

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.14'
testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4'
testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1-groovy-2.4'
```

My test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = RecruitApplication.class) 
class QuestionnaireServiceSpec extends Specification {

@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo

@Autowired
private QuestionnaireRepo repo

@Autowired
private QuestionnaireService sut

private static User newUser = new User.UserBuilder()
        .firstName("Candidate")
        .lastName("A")
        .status(User.Status.ACTIVE)
        .email("canA@new.pl")
        .build()

void "should create new questionnaire for candidate A"() {
    given:
    userRepo.save(newUser)
    String userId = userRepo.findByEmail(newUser.email).id
    assert userId

    when:
    sut.createQuestionnaireForUser(userId)

    then:
    repo.count() > 0
}
}
```

Comment: is it eing run in eclipse ? Is it a maven project ? can you do a mvn clean build and then update maven project once in that case ?

Comment: It's ran in IntelliJ and its a gradle project, and yes I can run a clean build (without tests)

Comment: ok, I found the reason. My Lombok builder was badly used. For some reason Groovy didn't throw any issues. I had to rewrite the test in pure Java. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So the problem was with the way I used Lombok builder. 
For some reason IntelliJ didn't show any errors when I created a new User object from the Lombok builder. 
The problem was with line:

```
 new User.UserBuilder()
```

it should be

```
 User.builder()
```

Comment: So you did not have to rewrite the test in pure Java as you said earlier, just correct your mistake, right?